# How to get access to the chromecast icon programaticailly

Tags: chromecast, castcompanionlibrary

I am trying to get a reference to the MediaRouteButton which is the cast icon and I am getting a null value all the time. Just wanted to see if anyone knows how to get a reference to this button. I am using a onGlobalLayoutListener to get notifications.

Comment: Could you explain (1) your use case and (2) are you using CCL?

Comment: I am using the CCL Library but I am trying to use ShowcaseView https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView I can't get the showcase view to show. The problem is I am getting null. I can post a snippet but cannot post code because it is private company.

Comment: `final View button = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.media_route_menu_item);`
                
) This is what I am trying to call and it is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CCL, you should be easily able to use ShowCaseView; take a look at the [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) app and see how it does it, basically you can use the callback `onCastDeviceDetected()` to be notified when the cast button appears and then do something like:

```
        Menu menu = mToolbar.getMenu();
        View view = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item).getActionView();
        if (view != null && view instanceof MediaRouteButton) {
            new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                    .setTarget(new ViewTarget(view))
                    .setContentTitle(R.string.touch_to_cast)
                    .build();
        }
```

This assumes you have a ToolBar.

EDIT: 
If you have an ActionBar, try the following:

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
    .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.MEDIA_ROUTE_BUTTON))
    .setContentTitle(R.string.touch_to_cast)
    .build();
```

At some point, I had submitted a patch to ShowCaseView project to cover MediaRoute button so hopefully that still works; I haven't tried that lately since I am using Toolbar now.

Comment: Yeah the problem is I don't have a toolbar. I am using an action bar.

Comment: I edited and added an alternate approach, give that a try